# SQL Smarty template not to list category

Tags: php, smarty

[image]

Category in the database as in the picture

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pm_categories ORDER BY name ASC";
    $result_t = mysql_query($sql) OR die(mysql_error());
        
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_t))
    {
        $data[] = $row; 
    }
    
    $smarty->assign('data', $data);

?>
```

The above code list all the categories by name in the database. What I want is to list one by one by `Id`, how can I do that?

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 (2013), and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0 (2015). Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Comment: You really need to consider moving 20 years into the future.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pm_categories ORDER BY name ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  //output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row["table_field"];   // Name is the field of pm_categories table
  }
}
```